# Internet explorer automation accessing image

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

Hi i have a c# IE automation script and i am trying to retrieve the image from a HTMLImgClass, i cant get the image from cache because its not saved and i cant just resend a request to the src because a new image returns, so i need a way to access the Image in the browsers memory.

```
captcha_image = (HTMLImgClass)GetElementByPosition("img", 0, ie1);
```

The object is retreived with the above assignement, which works fine, but i have no idea which of the methods available i can use to get the image.

Thanx for your time

SOLVED
For others interested, i solved it this way, i decided to copy the image to clipboard and then save it as a bmp

```
captcha_image = (HTMLImgClass)GetElementByPosition("img", 0, ie1);
                                    IHTMLImgElement captcha_image1 = (IHTMLImgElement)captcha_image;
                                    IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)wb1.Document;
                                    IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange)((HTMLBody)doc.body).createControlRange();
                                    imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement)captcha_image1);

                                    imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
                                    using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
                                    {
                                        bmp.Save(@"C:\skt.bmp");
                                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that this is related to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677088/c-sharp-and-internet-explorer-automation-accessing-the-cache). As suggested in [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10679038/1318472), if the image hasn't been saved to disk cache, you won't be able to access it there.

A solution is to force your browser to go through a proxy for all requests, and therefore to store the captcha images as they are being requested in the first place. I've used [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for this in the past.

In Fiddler2, you can change the `OnBeforeResponse` hook to save the image by code similar to the following:

```
    if (oSession.uriContains("captcha")){      // change as needed
        oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
        var filename = oSession.url;           // get an appropriate file name
        oSession.SaveResponseBody(filename);   // store the file
    }
```

Now as long as the file being saved by this script can later be found by your program (usually by keying off something in the URL), you're in business.

Comment: Yes yamen it is related, i was trying to avoid using the proxy, since this object has accessible the captcha height and width i think the string64 or something should be accessable also.

Comment: It isn't. The height and width is part of the HTML structure. The actual image is a whole different resource.

Comment: Well here's another answer that solves it without using the clipboard if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899417/saving-images-from-a-webbrowser-control